# Check if multiple Bash variable are empty/not set and run this or that

Tags: bash, variables

I am trying to populate/generate file depending if multiple variables are set/not empty or not. But in both cases it always behave like they both are set:

```
if [[ -z $VAR1=="" || -z $VAR2=="" ]]; then
  echo "VARs not set"

cat <<EOF > file
1
2
3
EOF

else
  echo "VARs are set"

cat <<EOF > file
1
2
3
4
5
EOF

fi
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `-z $VAR1==""` is always true; you probably mean `-z $VAR1` or `$VAR1 == ""`

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ would have given you valuable hints.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yeah, silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the answer is using `[[`, not `[` -- that's important, because using `[ -z $VAR ]` has subtle bugs and needs to be `[ -z "$VAR" ]`, whereas `[[ -z $VAR ]]` is correct even without the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just -z $VAR

```
if [[ -z $VAR1 || -z $VAR2 ]]; then
  echo "VARs NOT set -- "
cat <<EOF > file
1
2
3
EOF
else
  echo "VARs are set"
cat <<EOF > file
1
2
3
4
5
EOF
fi
```

Comment: There are *two* parts of this answer that are important. Without the switch from `[` to `[[`, code remains subtly buggy; that could stand to be called out in the English text.